# "Please make sure your passwords match" - Password error in Checkout with New Registration form

Tags: onepage-checkout, ce-1.8.1.0, register

I have been facing issue with Magento registration, when ever when I try to checkout with new registration, I get an password mismatch error "Please make sure your passwords match."
whereas the password entered is correct, but still I get the mismatch error, because of this, the user is unable to register itself and checkout the order,

[image]

The error I am getting in browser console is ,
[image]

**Update:**
By default, when I click "Register" option in checkout step, the registration form shows saved username and password of some other page in "Fax" and "Passwords" fields. So I deleted it and typed new password. Then I tried to print the values of "pass.value" and "conf.value" before the line `"return (pass.value == conf.value);"` in the file `/js/prototype/validation.js.` . But When I print the values I got "my saved password" in `pass.value` variable and "empty value" in `conf.value` variable.

How can I fix this problem ? 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: is there any error in console ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt: I have updated the question with "error message in console".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you absolutely sure the passwords match? turn the fields into text fields to test it.
Also take a look at how the retype password validation works.
In the file `/js/prototype/validation.js` there is this for password validation:

```
 ['validate-cpassword', 'Please make sure your passwords match.', function(v) {
            var conf = $('confirmation') ? $('confirmation') : $$('.validate-cpassword')[0];
            var pass = false;
            if ($('password')) {
                pass = $('password');
            }
            var passwordElements = $$('.validate-password');
            for (var i = 0; i < passwordElements.size(); i++) {
                var passwordElement = passwordElements[i];
                if (passwordElement.up('form').id == conf.up('form').id) {
                    pass = passwordElement;
                }
            }
            if ($$('.validate-admin-password').size()) {
                pass = $$('.validate-admin-password')[0];
            }
            return (pass.value == conf.value);
        }],
```

This is a good place to debug.
Maybe your markup is wrong and this fails.
try to log something before the returns statement `return (pass.value == conf.value);`.
See what the `pass` and `conf` fields are. Maybe you have an other password field in the page and the value for your password confirmation is matched against that one.

**[EDIT]**

I think I found the problem. Like I suspected there is an element with the id `confirmation` in your page. Everything happens because the login/register popup you have in every page. The one you get when you click the "Login/register" link in the top left corner.
There is a password confirmation field in that form with the id `confirmation`.
That's what it gets validated when you submit your form.
To fix this, I would take the easy way out.
I would remove the popup in the checkout page.
There are also other methods but this is the easiest. You don't need anyway the login and registration form in the checkout page because your can already do that in the checkout process.

Comment: Yes, I tested with text field. Password is correct. ok I ll try these instructions :)

Comment: Hi, I have tested the registration form in validation.js and updated the question with the actual values I get in password field. But still I am not able to fix the issue. Please check my updated question. Thank You.

Comment: @BalajiKandasamy. Notice that the validation method starts with this line: `var conf = $('confirmation') ? $('confirmation') : $$('.validate-cpassword')[0];`. Is there an element with the id `confirmation` in your page?

Comment: @BalajiKandasamy. Is your website public? I think I could help you better if I had a link to the website.

Comment: I have checked registration in "incognito window" Chrome, it is working correctly. But not submitting in normal window, there is my saved username and password of some other page showing in 'Fax' field and 'Password' field. I get the same saved password even after I deleted it and typed new password.

Comment: @BalajiKandasamy. See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Problem

Well this is a common problem that is encountered in Magento 1.9.1.0. When a User registers (doesn’t matter if its during checkout or from the Create an Account link) the user keeps getting the password mismatch error even though the password is re-entered correctly.

Reason

The validation method was changed in v1.9.1.

Earlier: `$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();`

Now: `$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();`

So the children of class Mage_Customer_Model_Customer should use `getPasswordConfirmation()` instead of `getConfirmation()`

Solution

Go to file `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`

Find the below code : `$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();`
Change this to : `$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();`

If this still doesn’t work then add it to a condition mentioned below

```
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getModuleName() == ‘onepagecheckout’) {
    $confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
} else {
    $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what that worked for me. It covers both the stand-alone registration page (`/customer/account/create/`) and the checkout registration page (`/checkout/onepage/?register`).

Look for the same `$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();` line and change it to:

```
    $confirmation = $this->getConfirmation() ? $this->getConfirmation() : $this->getPasswordConfirmation();

    if ($password != $confirmation) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy file `/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php` and edit with your favorite PHP editor.
Around line number 845 replace

```
$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
```

with

```
$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation() ? $this->getConfirmation() : $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
```

Save and try again to registration during checkout proceed

Bit it would be a lot better to make a rewrite instead of editing core files, even in `app/code/local`.

Comment: you should never edit core files.

Comment: thanks all. it works for me. i've tested on magento 1.9.1.0 with extend it to local/Mage

Answer (score -3):

Unless this truly is a core bug, I wouldn't recommend changing core files.But i sloved this way Open app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Customer.php and edit your code like below

```
$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
    $passwordconfirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
    //if ($password != $confirmation) {
    if (!(($password == $confirmation) || 
          ($password == $passwordconfirmation))) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
    }
```

Comment: So, apart from the core bug (which you do not recommend yourself): Why are you trying to compare the password with the confirmation (code)?

Comment: i know you are right but i just share my solution if you have any other solution then just share so that i learn something