# CE1.9.1 Please make sure your password match issue during User registration

Tags: magento-1.9, error, validation, form-validation, password

I am encountering this issue in CE1.9.1.

When a User registers (doesn't matter if it's during checkout or from the Create an Account link) the user keeps getting the password mismatch error even though the password is re-entered correctly.

The form validation does not indicate a miss-match, but once a user clicks on Register it returns the mismatch error.

There is no errors in the chrome console...

I found this: ["Please make sure your passwords match" - Password error in Checkout with New Registration form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37381/please-make-sure-your-passwords-match-password-error-in-checkout-with-new-re)

But I don't believe it is the same error.

I need to fix it soon, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This fixes the error in checkout cart but to get the "My Account" section to work I had to disable the compiler in ( admin|system|tools|compilation). ( re-compiling would probably work as well)

Answer (score 24):

Children of class `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` should use `getPasswordConfirmation()` instead of `getConfirmation()`

Upd: In class `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer`, method `validate()` was changed

Before v1.9.1:

```
$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
```

After:

```
$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
```

- https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror/blame/master/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php#L841
- https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror/commits/magento-ce-1.9.1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

Comment: Note also that you should check any controller overrides as well, not just models that extend this class!

Comment: The mind boggles how something so critical as to stop an ecommerce store allowing purchases can make it through QA and into an official release.

Comment: Also in some extensions need to change setConfirmation() to setPasswordConfirmation(). That was FireCheckout in my case. Class: TM_FireCheckout_Model_Type_Standard, method: _validateCustomerData().

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I was able to solve the issue.

I have to mention it is really not good that magento core files have this kind of issues when they secure the passwords, guess the core developers forgot some simple things.

Ok, so to fix this issue you have to override the core customer model in local like `app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`. In that go to around line no. 843 (if you haven't already overriden) or go to line `if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'StringLength', array(6))) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The minimum password length is %s', 6);
        }` and add the following code below that block:

```
//To match passwords in both Create account and Checkout register pages start
    if ( Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER') == Mage::getUrl('customer/account/create') )
      $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
    else
      $confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
    //To match passwords in both Create account and Checkout register pages end
```

After this the password and confirm password will match on both "Checkout" and "Create Account" pages.

Hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 3):

If anybody still can't figure out, why this is happening:
The Conlabz Useroptin extension (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/newsletter-double-opt-in-for-customers.html) can cause this behavior aswell.

Update 1.1.0 of said extension adds 1.9 compatibility

Answer (score 3):

I have an extension that was overriding the AccountController.php and was having the same issue for Magento Platforms below 1.9.1

My solution was;

```
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.9.1', '<=')) {        
$customer->setPasswordConfirmation($request->getPost('confirmation'));
}

if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.9.0', '>=')) {
$customer->setConfirmation($request->getPost('confirmation'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me neither `$this->getPasswordConfirmation()` nor `$this->getConfirmation()` worked. Both returned an empty string. So I ended up in accessing the POST parameter directly, in `/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php` (yes, better use a copy in `/app/code/local`):

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['confirmation']))
    $confirmation = $_REQUEST['confirmation'];
else
    $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
```

Comment: ha ha good crack :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution was

```
$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation(); // test works for Create, fails for Checkout
    if ($password != $confirmation) {
        $confirmation = $this->getConfirmation(); // test works for Checkout fails for Create
        if ($password != $confirmation) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because of this  change in 1.9.1 update. You have to update your extensions code
-Customer passwords are no longer stored in clear text during registration.

Comment: I see, I'll check the extension codes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue as I am using third party extension for checkout so this issue has to come

I have solved that error by doing following steps

> 1) in my module I search for `confirmation`
>
> 2) check that it is setting data for `customer` model
>
> 3) then change key to `password_confirmation` from `confirmation`

I follow above steps to debug the issue and solved it.

Answer (score -3):

Hi Friends This Problem Can be resolved by doing below steps:

Step 1: Open This file `/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php`
Step 2: Find This line in `Customer.php` `$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();`
Step 3: Replace That that line with  `$confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();`

Your Problem is now Resolved.

Comment: Unless this truly is a core bug, I wouldn't recommend changing core files.