# Please make sure your password match issue during User registration

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

I managed to fix this issue following this Question:

[CE1.9.1 Please make sure your password match issue during User registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46404/ce1-9-1-please-make-sure-your-password-match-issue-during-user-registration?newreg=9a6d19851d2241f0bf040ac461dd2cf8)

But the error still occurs when Checking out, and registering from a the Mobile.

I'll appreciate any help on the issue.

Comment: you might have a different name of password confirmation field for the customer registration.phtml in mobile theme. It should be 'confirmation'